# isNaN not working at all

Tags: javascript, html

So here is my HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="q_wow_wod"> </td> <td> <input type="submit" value="Add item" onClick="return validNumber(q_wow_wod) && confirm('Item will be added');" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is my associated JavaScript:

```
function validNumber(zone_txt) {
    if (isNaN(zone_txt) == false) {
        alert("Please, enter a number") ;
        return false ;
    } else {
        return true ;
    }
}
```

When I set the if with `== false`, it always goes into the `else` (`return true`). If I put `== true`, it always goes into the `if` (`return false`) – this no matter what I type in the textbox. This is driving me crazy. What’s going on?

Comment: Of course an object is not a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (isNaN(zone_txt) == false ) {
```

“If `zone_txt` is not not a number”
”If `zone_txt` is a number”

Just use `if (isNaN(zone_txt))`. Next, you’re passing the `<input>`, not the string inside the `<input>`; `if (isNaN(zone_txt.value))` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing now is testing the *element* with `name="q_wow_wod"`, which isn't a number. What you need to do is test its *value*:

```
return validNumber(q_wow_wod.value) && confirm('Item will be added');
```

assuming you've defined `var q_wow_wod` somewhere earlier.